# appending table rows to existing header

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I use some JQuery that appends table rows dynamically.

I would like the header row to be in the static HTML (which I have added) and the JQuery just to add additional rows onto it. However the rows never line up with the header, in fact all seem to go in the first cell of the row, rather than spreading out the inputs into the correct column.

This is the JQuery adding the row:

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Claims/BlankEditorRow',
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#editorRows").append(html);
            $('#editorRows .date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is the partial the JQuery adds:

```
   <tr class="editorRow table ">
     <td >

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selecteduserid, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserID", "FirstName"))</td>

    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingDate)</td>
        <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours)</td>    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageCost)</td>    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TravelCost)</td>

    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)</td>

    <td>
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the table in the view being added to:

```
  <table id="editorRows"  >
   <tr  >
         <th >
             Heading1</th>
    <th>
Heading2</th>
        <th>
Heading3</th>    <th>
Heading4</th>    <th>
Heading5</th>
    <th>
Heading6</th>
    <th>
Heading7</th>
        <td>
Delete Header
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thank you.

**EDITS:**

Action:

```
public PartialViewResult BlankEditorRow()
{

    LineViewModel vm = new LineViewModel();
    vm.users = getUserList();
    vm.categories = getcatList();
    vm.MeetingDate = DateTime.Now;
    vm.SubCatID = 1;//need to set as not currently required therefore as null allowed, it doesnt put default value in
    // vm.users = new List(db.users,"UserID","FirstName");
    // ViewBag.SubmissionUserID = new SelectList(db.users,"UserID","FirstName");
    return PartialView("NewRow", vm);
}
```

Full new row view:

```
@model authentication.ViewModels.LineViewModel


@using authentication.WebUI.Helpers
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("LineViewModels"))
{



   <tr class="editorRow table ">
     <td >

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selecteduserid, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserID", "FirstName"))</td>
    <td>
Category @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selectedcatid, new SelectList(Model.categories, "CatID", "CatName"))</td>
    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingDate)</td>
        <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours)</td>    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageCost)</td>    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TravelCost)</td>

    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)</td>
            <td>
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
</td>
</tr>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert 8 cells and change your HTML to

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/WJw3f/)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
        <th>Heading4</th>
        <th>Heading5</th>
        <th>Heading6</th>
        <th>Heading7</th>
        <th>Delete Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="editorRows"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you. I note I omitted the <tbody> tag. I also fixed different number of cells. Unfortunately if I use my original Jquery with your amendments it still doesnt work. It puts the contents in the first cell I think. Interestingly it does work if I put some html in the jquery direct (as per your post before the amendment) - but I dont think that will accomodate my dropdown lists and razor @.

Comment: Then you need to show the output from the claims/blamkeditorrows - obviously there is something wrong

Comment: thanks for your time. Added above. I think it may have something to do with the begincollectionitem (taken from Scott Sanderson's blog on variable lists).

Comment: I would not be able to tell. You need to post actual rendered html for me to test

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mplungjan for your help. I figured out the final bit, I had to move the  tag in my partial BEFORE the @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("LineViewModels")) line. This worked perfectly. As follows:

```
@model authentication.ViewModels.LineViewModel


@using authentication.WebUI.Helpers
   <tr class="editorRow table ">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("LineViewModels"))
{




     <td >

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selecteduserid, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserID", "FirstName"))</td>
    <td>
Category @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selectedcatid, new SelectList(Model.categories, "CatID", "CatName"))</td>
    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MeetingDate)</td>
        <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours)</td>    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageCost)</td>    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TravelCost)</td>

    <td>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)</td>
            <td>
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
</td>


}

       </tr>
```